# using LEFT JOIN produces different results than using IN

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, dynamics-crm-2011

I am wondering whether you can uncover this mystery of why these two queries, that should be producing the same exact results, are in fact producing different results. The first query is producing the incorrect result.

The following query shows that `o.OwnerId=b.systemuserid` is never true:

```
select distinct o.assignedto,b.systemuserid 
  from Opportunity o
  left join crmtestdb.dm1_mscrm.dbo.systemuserbase b
    on o.OwnerId = b.systemuserid
```

because it returns all nulls on the right side:

[image]

Whereas this query shows that `o.OwnerId=b.systemuserid` is indeed true for some records:

```
select distinct assignedto 
  from Opportunity
 where assignedto in (select distinct systemuserid 
                       from crmtestdb.dm1_mscrm.dbo.systemuserbase)
```

and this shows that they do have those fields in common:

[image]

What's going on here? What am I doing wrong? Please let me know if you need clarification on anything.

Comment: You have an accepted answer but there are two differences.  The first and second are not comparing the same same columns.  The first is a left join where the second mimics a join.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
select distinct 
    o.assignedto,
    b.systemuserid 
from Opportunity o
left join  crmtestdb.dm1_mscrm.dbo.systemuserbase b
    on o.OwnerId=b.systemuserid 
    --here you are matching Onwer to sysuser

select distinct 
    assignedto 
from Opportunity
where assignedto in (
    select distinct 
        systemuserid 
        --here you are matching assignedto to sysuser
        --this is not equivilant
    from crmtestdb.dm1_mscrm.dbo.systemuserbase
    )
```

You are not matching on the same things. In one query you are selecting Assignedto and matching `OwnerID` to `sytemuserID` in the second you are searching where assigned to is `IN` systemuserId  Try changing the second query to

```
select distinct 
    assignedto 
from Opportunity
  where OwnerId in (
    select distinct 
        systemuserid 
    from crmtestdb.dm1_mscrm.dbo.systemuserbase
    )
```

Comment: I get it is the accepted answer but if o.OwnerId=b.systemuserid is never true then I am surprised it fixed the second.  I would have guess the fix was the other way around.  +1 to you